# How to send data from React to NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

This is the code of mine where it consist of React File and Js File.

```
// React File //
... 

searchdata = this.state.value;        
console.log(`Search Data : ${searchdata}`);                
axios.post(BASE_URL + '/nameSearch',searchdata)  //
... 

// Js File //
...

app.post(('/nameSearch'),function(req,res)
{
console.log(req.body);
datasearch = req.body;
console.log(`This name search is :`+datasearch);
});

...
```

The errors :
undefined

The name search is :undefined

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove the wrapping parenthesis from ('/nameSearch') make it '/nameSearch'.
Then, in order to access request body in nodejs you need to use a body parser.
So in your nodejs file add the following code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Also do not forget to install body-parser in your project by doing:

```
npm i --s body-parser
```

in your project's root directory.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!

Here is my latest code.

```
//  React File
...
    searchdata = this.state.value;
    console.log(`Data Search : ${searchdata }`);
    const datasearch = {
        searchdata:this.state.value
    }
    axios.post(BASE_URL + '/nameSearch',datasearch)
...
//
// Js File
app.post('/nameSearch',function(req,res){
console.log(req.body.searchdata);
datasearch = req.body.searchdata;
console.log(`This name search is :`, datasearch);
})
...
//
```

It Works ! The output from react text box to be displayed in nodejs console.

Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

try to remove `()`

```
const searchdata = this.state.value;        
console.log(`Search Data : ${searchdata}`);                
axios.post(BASE_URL + '/nameSearch',searchdata)


app.post('/nameSearch',function(req,res){
 console.log(req.body);
 const datasearch = req.body;
 console.log(`This name search is :`, datasearch);
})
```

Comment: Still same as undefined

Comment: @HazimanHamzil check edited code above. If it still occurs error, let me know your searchdata `this.state.value`

Comment: I removed the () and also the semicolon , result in the error is still undefined

Comment: The search data value : dadaada 

which is what i put in the text box in react file

Comment: If `searchdata` is not Object, try this axios.post(BASE_URL + '/nameSearch',{searchdata})

Comment: I change the searchdata to {searchdata} , the output is still undefined, was wondering is my backend code at the request is correct or not

Comment: there is no error in node code. Can you get `console.log(req.body)`? I think there is error in react app

Comment: console.log(req.body) the output is undefined.